# How to wake a device in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

**Condition:** There is an application which should wake up the device (the device screen should turn on) and show a notification at a time. I have made it through BroadcastReceiver.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent)
{
    //Wake up the deivce
    wakeDevice(context)

    //Call notification display function
    makeBarNotification(context)
}
```

Everything that concerns the awakening of the device I have written in a separate function. Code below:

```
private fun wakeDevice(context: Context)
{
    //Create Power manager
    val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager

    //Create WakeLock
    val myWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, "MyApp:NotificationWakelockTag")

    //Specify the duration of work (In this case, 5 seconds)
    myWakeLock.acquire(5 * 1000L)

    //ReleaseWakeLock
    myWakeLock.release()
}
```

> I have written in manifest this code: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

**Problem:** The device does not wake up and an error occurs: "`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify a valid wake lock level.`" 
Error pointing to the line where I create WakeLock (`val myWakeLock = ...`)

**Hypothesis:** Probably the problem is  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. This code is recommended to be used instead of `PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` here: [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK)

**Question:** How then to wake the device in BroadcastReceiver if the code `PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` is deprecated, and the code`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` leads to an error.